# Reuse Codes In Laravel

Tags: laravel, oop, reusability, code-reuse

I've some

> if() {
>
> } else {
>
> }

condition, which is used in several times. I want to reuse them rather typing them over and over again.

here is my controller source code: [MyController.php](https://gist.github.com/Illusionist3886/767ae06b125b80dec24bf1b136670295)

Comment: You have to explain your question bit more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply put this snippet into a function say `buildExamData`:

```
protected function buildExamData($examdata) {
    $examIdsNesting = [];

    foreach ($examdata as $examdatum) {
       $examIdsNesting[] = array(
          'Exam Name' => $examdatum->Name,
          'Exam Code' => $examdatum->ExamCode,
          'Exam Details' => $examdatum->Details,
          'Exam Owner' => $examdatum->Owner,
       );
    }
    return $examIdsNesting;
}
```

Then each time you want to perform this action just call `buildExamData()` eg.:

```
public function GetListOfExams(Request $request)
{
    //select Name, ExamCode,Details, Owner, from exams where owner = Owner and status = 1;
    $owner = $request->get('owner'); //get this from GET request
    $status = 1; //it is intialized here
    $examdata = Exam::select('Name', 'ExamCode', 'Details', 'Owner')->where(
        array(
            'Owner' =>  $owner,
            'status'=>  $status
        )
    )->get();

    return $examdata->isEmpty()
        ? response()->json('Exam not found for this Owner', 404)
        : response()->json($this->buildExamData($examdata), 200);
 }
```

> Please note that I have made a little refactor to the `buildExamData()` function so you don't need `array_push()`
>
> Ps: if you don't want to expose your source code I can delete the portion of the code and just leave the explanations